# Proper system drive root permissions on Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11

My Windows 11 pc has been reporting some unusual permissions errors recently, including but not limited to the **permissions incorrectly ordered** warning.   I think the system drive's root permissions have been changed somehow.  How can I reset them?

Would it make sense to run `CACLS C:\ /S` with the SDDL from a machine that is working correctly?

On the troubled machine, I run CACLS and get this:

```
PS C:\> cacls c:\
c:\ <Account Domain not found>(special access:)
                              SYNCHRONIZE
                              FILE_READ_DATA
                              FILE_EXECUTE
                              FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES

    <Account Domain not found>(special access:)
                              SYNCHRONIZE
                              FILE_READ_DATA
                              FILE_EXECUTE
                              FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES

    BUILTIN\Administrators:(ID)F
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(ID)F
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(ID)F
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(ID)F
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(ID)C
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(ID)C
    BUILTIN\Users:(ID)R
    BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(ID)(special access:)
                                  GENERIC_READ
                                  GENERIC_EXECUTE
```

Or the SDDL version

```
PS C:\> cacls c:\ /s
c:\ "D:(A;;0x1000a1;;;S-1-15-3-65536-1888954469-739942743-1668119174-2468466756-4239452838-1296943325-355587736-700089176)(A;;0x1000a1;;;S-1-15-3-65536-1171677023-2469935273-3317266010-2937768231-83730487-3606222557-2674643231-2098219660)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;OICIIOID;GA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIIOID;GA;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;AU)(A;OICIIOID;SDGXGWGR;;;AU)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;OICIIOID;GXGR;;;BU)"
```

Comment: This is not a regular Windows 11 issue. You would have made some changes for this to happen. Can you reverse these changes?

Comment: Is your machine connected to a AD domain?

Comment: The machine was once a domain member, but I note that the S-1-15-3 SIDs are not from an NT domain.   Raymond Chen explains, "[SIDs of the form S-1-15-3-xxx are app capability SIDs. These SIDs are present in the token of apps running in an app container, and they encode the app capabilities possessed by the app.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220503-00/?p=106557)" SIDs with this prefix are even newer.   ([S-1-15-2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220502-00/?p=106550) is the domain prefix.)

Comment: John: the machine was upgraded to Windows 11, and the ACL probably come from before that upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin is known for causing this problem when used to manipulate files
in your the Windows file-system with `/cygdrive/`.
If that's your case, see the post
[Creating folders in Cygwin results in incorrectly ordered permissions, failure to open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550517/creating-folders-in-cygwin-results-in-incorrectly-ordered-permissions-failure-t)
on how to avoid it in the future. In general, using Cygwin
in this way is bad practice and should be avoided.

For resolving the problem see the post
[Getting "Incorrectly ordered" error message when setting a folder permission to a domain group using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623764/getting-incorrectly-ordered-error-message-when-setting-a-folder-permission-to).

This post explains that Access Control Entries (ACEs) in the
object's Access Control List (DACL) need to be specified in a
certain order.
The accepted answer contains a PowerShell script that rebuilds the ACEs
in the right order, while keeping all the existing permissions,
without the need for taking control of the object (which should NEVER
be done to the `C:\` folder!).
The script needs to be run with Administrator permissions.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not using Cygwin, but I do use Microsoft's WSL.
The post with the PowerShell fix script looks helpful.

Comment: The output from `Get-ACL c:\ | Format-List` is much more readable than CACLS, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`icacls c:\ /save aclfile` on a working machine will give you portable machine-readable SDDL record, that may be `icacls c:\ /restore`'ed on broken machine. There will be something like

`D:AI(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;;0x100020;;;WD)S:PAI(ML;OINPIO;NW;;;HI)`

inside.

What is above is the real customized ACL for my win11 22h2 system drive. The record *includes mac label* `S:PAI(ML;OINPIO;NW;;;HI)`, but does *not* include *audit* ACE's. If you need to port audit ACE's, powershell `get-acl -audit` will give them to you, but I am not sure `icacls` will apply them.

`icacls c:\ /restore` recursively walks through c:\ and updates *all inheritable* permissions on files and folders, and does *not* touch immediate permissions, that is what you want, I suppose.

For some weird reason `icacls /restore` does not directly accept *aclfile* made by `icacls /save`. You need to put a single dot w/o qoutes into 1st line of aclfile, i.e:

`.` (linebreak) `D:AI(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;;0x100020;;;WD)S:PAI(ML;OINPIO;NW;;;HI)`

The `S-1-15-3-65536-1888...9176` you see in your c:\ drive's ACL is not a damage. It comes right with Win11 22H2 installation image, got noticed and complained multiple times [Account Unknown (S-1-15-3-65536-18 ...), 2022-10-31](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/account-unknowns-1-15-3-65536-1888954469-739942743/d6ac7e97-92c3-40f8-a6bb-0a195ad944ce), [Account Unknown, 2022-07-28](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/account-unknown.7996/), etc. I did not come across any explanation from MS what it is.

I tried to remove `S-1-15-3-65536-1888...9176` ACE from system drive ACL, but it resurrects after reboot. Fascinating enough, audit does not catch who is adding there.

Comment: Thank you jabba.  I found an article by Raymond Chen that explain SIDs of this format:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220503-00/?p=106557

Comment: I am aware of, thank you. Unfortunately, the article does not disclose a meaning of this particular sid, and does not disclose a way to discover a meaning of a particular sid. Actually, MS does not provide a way to discover app capability sids in a system.